# Reverse the order of digits in a large number

Tags: r

I am currently trying to write code that would give me the reversed version of a number if given. This is currently what I have which is down below. I do not have the help of my professor so I'm trying to learn this on my own.

```
Print("Enter a Number:")
{
rev=0
random number<-function(n,r)
}
while (n>0)
r=n%%10
rev=rev*10+r
n=n%10
print ("Reverse number is:")
```

Comment: Several things here are unclear. What does the reversed version of a number mean? When you say it only works for large numbers, do you mean it *currently* is only working for large numbers, or you only *want* it to work for large numbers, or something else, and how are you defining large?

Comment: @Camille, Good afternoon Camille, He wants a code that will give any large number the flipped version of it. So for example 234 to 432 and only wants it for large numbers. He didn't define which large numbers he wanted as of now.

Comment: Also syntax problems: You have brackets placed where they don't need to be / shouldn't be. You declare a function but don't define it. Not sure what `random number` should be doing—object names can't have spaces in them. Your while loop should actually contain some expression in brackets, otherwise it isn't actually evaluating anything.  And where does `Print` come from, vs `print`?

Comment: Lastly, unless the last 5 lines are supposed to be inside the function definition, the variables `n` and `r` are undefined, and it's unclear what either of them are supposed to signify. It would also help if you explained what the algorithm is that you're using to reverse digits

Comment: If you are prompting the user to enter a number, why are you attempting to write a function to generate a random number? Instead use `readline` (rather than `print`) to get the input.

Comment: pharaoh78, I don't like this as a resolution of sorts, but ... have you gone through a tutorial to learn R? It feels like you're on day 1 or so of the language, and there are many components of R (or perhaps programming in general) that appear to be unclear to you. Unfortunately StackOverflow is not a good place to learn a language from scratch, and you won't find many good discussions that'll help you at this stage. I strongly suggest you go back to the tutorial the professor gave you and go over it again. (If they didn't, well ... something is missing from that syllabus.)

Comment: @pharaoh78, I wonder if I offended you or came across overly-critical in my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71326208/another-way-to-split-numbers-in-r-rstudio-with-the-code-below?noredirect=1#comment126075965_71326208). If I did, my apologies! Nothing intended. I didn't see that as a suggestion or justification to delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes:

```
n <- 12345 # An example
rev <- 0
while (n>0){ #Include Open and closed Curly braces
  r <- n %% 10
  rev <- rev*10 + r
  n <- n %/% 10 # Integer division is %/% and not %
}
sprintf("Reverse number is: %d", rev) # Use sprintf

[1] "Reverse number is: 54321"
```